# Please help me to understand jQuery's new .on method

Tags: jquery

I used to use .live but I am now trying to replace those with the better .on but I don't seem to understand the API instructions because the code below does nothing and I should be getting an alert. Can anyone see where I am messing this up?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Media Player</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/music-player.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

        <script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main-center">
            <h1>Please select your choice of music</h1>
            <a class="openplayer" data-genre="rock" href="#">Rock</a>
            <a class="openplayer"  data-genre="hip" href="#">Hip Hop</a>
            <a class="openplayer"  data-genre="country" href="#">Country</a>
            <a class="openplayer"  data-genre="featured" href="#">Featured Artist</a>
        </div> <!-- /.main-center -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($) {
                $('.openplayer').on('click', 'a', function(e){
                    var genre = $(this).data('genre');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert(genre);
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `on` on the container of the elements and pass it the selector of the elements you want to attach to. Your existing code is calling `on` not on the container but on the links themselves. Try:

```
$('.main-center').on('click', '.openplayer', function(e) {
    var genre = $(this).data('genre');
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(genre);
});
```

Comment: I thought I was doing that until I saw your code. Now I see what they meant by the "container" and the "element." That works and THANKS!!!  ( I will accept this answer as soon as the time allows )

Comment: this is exactly right. the .on event handler is a great addition to jQuery especially when you want to handle the event on lots of elements. if you have 1000 elements you want to handle, without .on we had 1000 event handlers (taking up memory and rendering time.) now we can leverage event bubbling to a single element and handle all 1000 elements with one handler.